# Keep getting 'Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET' when trying to deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I've been trying to deploy a rails app to heroku and have been having some issues. I did a good amount of poking around through the logs and on SO but couldn't find anything to point me in the proper direction. Then again I just might be missing something obvious. Anyway any help would be greatly appreciated.

Command

```
git push -f heroku master
```

LOGS

```
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-08-28T05:56:30+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-08-28T05:56:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-28T05:56:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-28T05:56:36+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-08-28T05:57:19+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by raphael.shejnberg@gmail.com
2012-08-28T05:57:19+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8bc52ce by raphael.shejnberg@gmail.com
2012-08-28T05:57:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-28T05:57:20+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-28T05:57:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 6287`

2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:6287
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/project.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0x00000003d3b3e8> (NoMethodError)
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/project.rb:4:in `<class:Project>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
 2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `safe_constantize'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
 2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-08-28T05:57:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-28T05:57:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-28T05:57:38+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET floating-sierra-9248.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
  2012-08-28T05:57:38+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET floating-sierra-   9248.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I had to remove part of the logs for it to format right and be readable, its a deprecation warning

```
2012-08-28T05:57:24+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
```

(called from  at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

Environment.rb

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Blog::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: Are you missing some of your log lines? It looks like there should be more above the line that says `from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in 'initialize'`. Could you post (an anonymized version of) everything that happens after you run `git push`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in this line of the log:

```
2012-08-28T05:57:27+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0x00000003d3b3e8> (NoMethodError)
```

Maybe the gem that you use to manipulate uploads and files is not installed. And remember that you can't use this gem without uploading your files to another server.

Comment: Well I tried installing paperclip but it already definitely was installed then I just tried removing it since it wasnt such a necessity but when I add/commit/push again I get the same error. I even did a search within the app folder for the line 'has_attached_file' and nothing turned up so Im a bit confused how its throwing a nomethoderror when the method isnt mentioned throughout the project anymore.